# Is the weekly limit for Vanguard Marks per character or per account?

Tags: destiny

So there is a weekly limit of 100 Vanguard Marks which can be earned each week, is this an account limit, or can I swap characters and then continue to earn marks?

I assume that I cannot trade them between characters though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is 100 Marks per Week, per Character and an inventory maximum of 200 per character.

Comment: Addendum: They are not an *item* in your inventory, and as a result you cannot place them in the bank nor trade them between characters.